# Aurelia: Set focus after last character in input text

Tags: autofocus, aurelia

When I use the focus.bind="setFocus" in FireFox the cursor goes to the beginning of the input and not to the end of the existing text.

In Chrome works fine.

How can I solve this?

Code:

```
<template bindable="value">
    <require from="./search.css"></require>

    <div class="section search">
        <form>
            <div class="container gutter-height-bottom">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 offset-md-2 offset-lg-2">
                        <input
                                placeholder="O que você está procurando?"
                                class="form-control form-control-lg"
                                focus.bind="true"
                                value.bind="value"
                                type="text"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```